# ASM code implementation for multiplying integer

Tags: assembly, arm

The following ASM code is used for finding the product of two integers by asking input from the user.

What is the purpose of implementing these following lines of code?

```
MOVNE R2, R2, LSL #1 
MOVNE R4, R4, LSL #1
TST R1, R4
```

Full code:

```
.global multiply

.text

multiply:
    MOV R2, R0 
    MOV R0, #0 
    MOV R3, #0 
    MOV R4, #1
loop:
    CMP R3, #0 
    MOVNE R2, R2, LSL #1 
    MOVNE R4, R4, LSL #1
    TST R1, R4
    BEQ iterate
    ADD R0, R0, R2

iterate:
    ADD R3, R3, #1
    CMP R3, #31
    BLE loop

exit:
    BX LR
```

Comment: From [tag:assembly] tag: "BE SURE TO ALSO TAG with the processor and/or instruction set you're using, as well as the assembler." Also, please fix formatting by indenting by four spaces (or selecting the code and hitting Ctrl-K, or Command-K).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're already aware that e.g. `3 * 11` can be rewritten as `3 * 1` + `3 * 2` + `3 * 8`. That latter form is basically how the code you've posted goes about calculating the result.

You've got the multiplicand and multiplier in `R0` and `R1`; let's call them `X` and `Y`, and a bit number (0..31) in `R3`; let's call that `N`.

So for each value of `N` you calculate `X << N`, i.e. `X * 2^N`. That's effectively what `CMP R3, #0` / `MOVNE R2, R2, LSL #1` does. The shift is just a single shift to the left, i.e. a doubling of the current value, but since you do that for every iteration except the first you end up with `X << N`.

Then you check if the `N`th bit of `Y` is set:

```
(CMP R3, #0 )
MOVNE R4, R4, LSL #1     @ R4 = 1 << N == 1 * 2^N
TST R1, R4               @ Set flags based on Y & (1 * 2^N)
```

If the `N`th bit of `Y` *was* set, you add `X << N` to the result. Then repeat for the next value of `N`, etc.

In the case of `3 * 11` (binary `0011` * `1011`) you have bits 0, 1 and 3 set in `Y`, so you get the result `(3 << 0) + (3 << 1) + (3 << 3)` == `3*1 + 3*2 + 3*8` == `3 + 6 + 24` == `33`.